# What was the point of this device in the Mandalorian?

Tags: the-mandalorian

**Mandalorian season 2 spoilers**

In episode 7 of season 2 of *The Mandalorian,* Din and Mayfeld break into an Imperial facility.  They have to use a certain device (I can't remember if it had a name) to get the information they need.  However, the device has a facial scanner that Mayfeld says he can't use because he's a criminal.  Din has to use it, removing his helmet.

Honestly, this seems like a convenient way for the plot to get Din to remove his helmet for Grogu's sake.  What was this device?  It should've recognized that Din wasn't in the Imperial army, so why would it work for him?  Is the device literally just checking that the person being scanned has a face?  If it worked like a fingerprint scanner, then Din should've not been able to use it because he doesn't have a record in the Empire.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mayfeld *could* use the facial scanner on the terminal and *was*, in fact, going to. The issue was there was someone in the Officer's Mess that Mayfeld served under and could potentially recognize him if he went in to access the terminal. There was never any implied issue that the scanner could identify specific people.

A plausible reason for why the scanner only needed to see a face is it could easily have been something akin to a CAPTCHA system that merely checks to see if a human is using the system. This is likely to prevent droids or non-Humans (whom the Empire harbored resentment towards) from using the terminal.

It should also be pointed out that Mayfeld was wanted by the New Republic. Not the Empire or what remained of it. He was concerned that Valin Hess would recognize him and that things could get complicated. Which, they in fact, did.

Comment: Ah, thank you, it's been a while since I've seen that episode.  Describing it as a CAPTCHA makes a lot of sense, thanks!

Comment: literally "I am not a robot" - https://shirtoid.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/R2Captcha.jpg